# ensuring correct configuration in different environments

Tags: configuration, development-environment

I usually change the connection string in config to connect either to a Test database or to a Production database.

I am afraid some day I will mix up them and execute activities that were intended for the Test database, but execute against the Production database.

Backups minimize impact, but is there something else that can be done to avoid this problem?

My environment is Visual Studio 2010, .NET, MySQL

Comment: it's called use different permissions in differrent environments

Comment: @Mitch> move that to an Answer, you're exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different account/permissions in different environments.

In a windows environment, use database roles mapped to Windows Groups (if your DB supports it).

Preferably, do not give developers everyday access to Production. If needed, create `DOMAIN\userName.admin` (or something similiar) accounts to be used in the rare circumstances that developers need to access  the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Deny the developer's accounts the rights/permissions to execute against production. Let's assume you have the ability to create A.D. accounts.

- Use your regular everyday account against your Dev and Test environments. Deny that account permission to Prod.
- Create and use another account when executing changes to Production. Name it something clear like `Idsa-Admin` or `Idsa-Prod`. This will force you to be explicit and create a connection or login with that account.